# How to sort a slice in go without mutating the original slice

Tags: go

In Golang, I am trying to sort a slice without mutating the original value

```
func main() {
    originalArray := []int{4, 2, 1, 1, 2}
    newArray := originalArray
    sort.Ints(newArray)

    fmt.Printf("%v", originalArray) // prints [1 1 2 2 4]
}
```

How can I sort a slice in `golang` without mutating the original value?

Comment: Don't use shorthand to make a copy(here, it is a shallow copy), use a loop to make a deep copy of the slice.

Comment: Terminological clarification: a "shallow copy" of an array is *exactly* what is required here. "Shallow" means "copy the first level of the composite data type, but reuse the pointer-based or atomic values contained therein".  The OP's code has `newArray := originalArray`, which is *not* a "copy" per common technical usage of "copy".  More: a "deep copy" requires not just a loop, but recursion (or another stack-based technique) in order to "deeply" copy the structure all the way down to immutable items (typically not just numbers, but often strings, depending on the language). Beware: cycles!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the original slice.

Use:

```
newArray := make([]int, len(originalArray))
copy(newArray, originalArray)
```

or:

```
newArray := append([]int{}, originalArray...)
```